# print element in an array row by row to get the index value of an array element java

Tags: java, arrays

I am iterating through an array as shown and I want to print out the individual element row by row in the array from the below snippet

**editted**
the array is fetching from a database json response as shown

```
// Extract data from json and store into ArrayList
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        dataList.add(json_data.getString("nameo"));
                        dataList.add(json_data.getString("id"));
                    }

                    strArrData = dataList.toArray(new String[dataList.size()]);
```

iterating thru the array here from the response

```
for(int i = 0; i <strArrData.length; i++){
    System.out.println("populated data1>>>> "+ strArrData[i]); //this is prints out the array elements but not row by row
}
```

Please how can I print the individual element in the array row by row eg

```
row 0 
item1 item2

row1
item3 item4
```

So that I can get an item in a specific index value eg

```
strArrData[2] will print item2 for instance
```

This is the output I am present getting

```
populated data1>>>> Item1
populated data1>>>> 0
populated data1>>>> Item2
populated data1>>>> 1
populated data1>>>> Item3
populated data1>>>> 2
```

Comment: can you show the output you're getting currently?

Comment: So a Row has two elements? strArrData[i] & strArrData[i+1]?

Comment: editted to show the output I am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassvsInstance {

    private int[][] strArrData = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}};

    public ClassvsInstance() {

        for (int i = 0; i < strArrData.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("row" + i + "\n"); // start new row 
            for (int j = 0; j < strArrData[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("\titem" + strArrData[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("\n"); // to new row 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassvsInstance();

    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
row0
    item1   item2   item3

row1
    item3   item4   item5

row2
    item4   item5   item6
```

Comment: strArrData  is gotten from toArray. Please go through the logic very well